# React Router changes URL but the page is still unchanged

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used custom browser history for programmatic navigation. for this purpose I created history in this way:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

then I gave the history to my Router as a props,

```
const App=()=>{
    const error=()=>{
        return <h1>webpage was not found</h1>
    }
    return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <div className="ui container">
                <Header/>
                <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList}/>
                <Route path="/delete/:id" component={StreamDelete}/>
                <Route path="/edit/:id" component={StreamEdit}/>
                <Route path="/show/:id" component={StreamShow}/>
                <Route path="/new" component={StreamCreate}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
    )
}
```

I used following code to forcibly navigate my app from StreamCreate page to StreamList page after action accomplishment. the URL changes but the page does not change.

```
export const createStream=(values)=>async(dispatch,getState)=>{
    const {userId}=getState().auth;
    const response=await jsonServer.post("/streams",{...values,userId});
    dispatch({type:'CREATE_POST', payload:response.data})
    history.push('/')
}
```

Comment: This code should work fine I think. Can you make a demo app on jsfiddle with this problem reproduced?

Comment: @C.Schubert The problem is currently solved by adding {forceRefresh:true} into browserHistory: `export default createBrowserHistory({forceRefresh:true})`